# Theoretical problem on uniform convergence of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I'm having difficulties trying to solve this problem :

> If $ f $ is differentiable and $ \forall x, y \in \Bbb R :\lvert f'(x) - f'(y) \rvert \le 3 \lvert x - y \rvert $, show that $ f_n $ converge uniformly to $ f' $, where $$ f_n(x) = \frac{f(x + \frac{1}{n}) - f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

This problem is very different from the usual investigation of uniform convergence for sequences of functions and I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the MVT, $f_n(x)= f'(c(n,x))$  for some $c(n,x) \in (x,x+1/n).$ Thus $$f_n(x) - f'(x) = f'(c(n,x))-f'(x),$$ which in absolute value is no more than $3/n.$ Therefore $f_n \to f'$ uniformly on $\mathbb R.$

Comment: This is very helpful but I don't understand the very last step where $ \lvert f'(c(n,x))-f'(x) \rvert \le \frac{3}{n} $. Could you please explain it to me? How did you find the value of $ \frac{3}{n} $?

Comment: $|f'(c(n,x)) - f'(x)| \le 3| c(n,x)-x| .$ But $c(n,x)\in (x,x+1/n) \implies | c(n,x)-x| <1/n.$

Comment: Your explanation was very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Write
$$
f_n(x)=n·(f(x+\tfrac1n)-f(x))=\int_0^1 f'(x+\tfrac sn)\,ds
$$

---

This is a specialization of the more general formula
$$
F(x+v)-F(x)=\int_0^1F'(x+sv)v\,ds,
$$
used for instance in the vector version of the mean-value theorem,
which in turn is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus for $G(s)=F(x+sv)$ with $G'(s)=F'(x+sv)v$.

---

In consequence, 
$$
|f_n(x)-f'(x)|\le\int_0^1|f'(x+\tfrac sn)-f'(x)|\,ds\\
\le\int_0^13\left|\frac sn\right|\,ds=\frac3{2n}
$$
which implies the postulated uniform convergence.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how did you find this integral and how to calculate it? If the above integral is $ \lt \infty $ does this implies that the sequence $ f_n(x) $ converges uniformly?

Comment: $f'$ is Lipschitz continuous, by hypothesis.